How do I read amplified voltage using an Arduino UNO
 void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(A3,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  double Temp_cel = 0;

  float pinreading = analogRead(A3);

 double volt_atinstant = map(pinreading, 0 , 1023, 0, 5);

  Serial.println(volt_atinstant);
}

I am trying to use an Arduino Uno to measure the amplified voltage being outputted from the following circuit

I am sure the amplified output voltage is correct as I've used another device to measure the output voltage but now I cant seem to figure out the correct way to map the reading of the Arduino uno "pinreading" to a correct voltage value. When I run the code it gives me a constant value of 3.00 volts
I feel I'm doing something wrong with the mapping.

The problem is using Arduino map() function incorrectly.
According to Arduino manuald, it returns integers, not floats.
If you want to scale X that is 0..1023 range to floats in 0..5 range, just multiply the float by 5.0 and divide by 1023.0.
